# Manipulating an object in a setTimeout function that was created by a previous setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

I have a function to perform an animation using setTimeout functions, structured as follows:

```
animation: function() {
  //first
  setTimeout(function(){
    makeObject({ ... }); // this makes '#object .secondary' on the DOM
  }, 500);
  //second
  setTimeout(function(){
    ...
  }, 1000);
  //third
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#object .secondary').doSomething();
  }, 1500);

}
```

I am creating an object associated with the '.secondary' CSS class in the first setTimeout function, then I am trying to select the object and manipulate it using the class name in the third function. However, the object remains unchanged after the third function executes, and I receive the error "Undefined is not a function". I think this is due to the fact that the setTimeouts execute at the same time, so the secondary object does not yet exist to be selected by the third function. So my question is this: how do I manipulate the secondary object from the third setTimeout function?

Comment: This means that `$('#object .secondary')` doesn't have an element named `doSomething`. Is it just a basic jQuery object, or is there a jQuery plugin that's supposed to give it a method `doSomething`?

Comment: The calls are actually d3 via `d3.select('#object').selectAll('.secondary').fadeOut(50);`

Comment: Are you saying the code is different from what you wrote here? Why?!?!

Comment: If you intend to use jQuery or Zepto functions like `$()` and `.fadeOut()`, have you included one of these libraries along with D3 in the page?

Comment: Yes I've included jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeouts on their own shouldn't be an issue. The 3rd will start around 1 second after the 1st.

But, the error you mentioned would be. Based on your comment:

> The calls are actually d3 via `d3.select('#object').selectAll('.secondary').fadeOut(50);`

It's because D3's [Selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections), that `d3.select()` and `.selectAll()` return, aren't related to jQuery and won't have its methods.

You'll have to either convert the collection from `d3` to `jQuery` before using `.fadeOut()`.

```
jQuery( d3.select('#object').selectAll('.secondary') ).fadeOut(50);
```

Or, use jQuery throughout the statement, as you'd suggested doing in your snippet:

```
jQuery('#object .secondary').fadeOut(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the 2nd&3rd Timeout in the previous one?
E.G.

```
animation:function() {
setTimeout(function() {
 makeObject(…);
 setTimeout(function() {
  ...
  setTimeout(function() {
   $('#object .secondary').doSomething();
  },500);
 },500);
},500);
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this could help.

Comment: Your answer includes 100,100,100 for the delay times, could you update your times to match the timing of the question?

Comment: This is wrong. It should be 500,500,500 instead of 500,1000,1500.